# Preserving special characters in text nodes using Python lxml module

Tags: python, lxml

I am editing an XML file that is provided by a third party.  The XML is used to recreate and entire environment and one is able to edit the XML to propogate the changes.  I was able to lookup the element I wanted to change through command line options and save the XML, but special characters are being escaped and I need to retain the special characters.  For example it is changing > to $gt; in the file during the .write operation.  This is affecting in all occurances of the XML document not just the node element (I think that is what it is called) Below is my code:

```
import sys
from lxml import etree
from  optparse import OptionParser

def parseCommandLine ():
   usage = "usage: %prog [options] arg"
   parser =  OptionParser(usage)
   parser.add_option("-f","--file",dest="filename",
                  help="Context File name including full path", metavar="CONTEXT_FILE")

parser.add_option("-k","--key",dest="key",
                  help="Key you are looking for in Context File i.e s_isAdmin", metavar="s_someKey")

parser.add_option("-v","--value",dest="value",
                  help="The replacement value for the key")

if len(sys.argv[1:]) < 3:
   print len(sys.argv[1:]) 
   parser.print_help()
   sys.exit(2)

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
return options.filename, options.key, options.value
Filename, Key,  Value=parseCommandLine()
parser_options=etree.XMLParser(attribute_defaults=True, dtd_validation=False,      strip_cdata=False)
doc = etree.parse(Filename, parser_options ) #Open and parse the file
print doc.findall("//*[@oa_var=%r]" % Key)[0].text 
oldval = doc.findall("//*[@oa_var=%r]" % Key)[0].text
val = doc.findall("//*[@oa_var=%r]" % Key)[0]
val.text = Value

print 'old value is  %s' % oldval
print 'new value is  %s' % val.text

root = doc.getroot()
doc.write(Filename,method='xml',with_tail=True,pretty_print=False)
```

Original file has this:

> tf.fm.FulfillmentServer >> /s_u01/app/applmgr/f

Saved version is being replaced with this:

```
tf.fm.FulfillmentServer &gt;&gt; /s_u01/app/applmgr/f
```

I have been trying to mess with pretty_print in the output side DTD validations on the parsing side and I am stumped.

Below is a diff from the changed file and and the original file:

I updated the s_cookie_domain only.

```
diff finprod_acfpdb10.xml_original finprod_acfpdb10.xml                             
Warning: missing newline at end of file finprod_acfpdb10.xml
1,3c1
< <?xml version = '1.0'?>
< <!-- $Header: adxmlctx.tmp 115.426 2009/05/08 08:46:29 rdamodar ship $ -->
< <!--
---
> <!-- $Header: adxmlctx.tmp 115.426 2009/05/08 08:46:29 rdamodar ship $ --><!--
13,14c11
<   -->
< <oa_context version="$Revision: 115.426 $">
---
>   --><oa_context version="$Revision: 115.426 $">
242c239
<          <cookiedomain oa_var="s_cookie_domain">.apollogrp.edu</cookiedomain>
---
>          <cookiedomain oa_var="s_cookie_domain">.qadoamin.edu</cookiedomain>
526c523
<          <FORMS60_BLOCK_URL_CHARACTERS oa_var="s_f60blockurlchar">%0a,%0d,!,%21,",%22,%28,%29,;,[,%5b,],%5d,{,%7b,|,%7c,},%7d,%7f,>,%3c,&lt;,%3e</FORMS60_BLOCK_URL_CHARACTERS>
---
>          <FORMS60_BLOCK_URL_CHARACTERS oa_var="s_f60blockurlchar">%0a,%0d,!,%21,",%22,%28,%29,;,[,%5b,],%5d,{,%7b,|,%7c,},%7d,%7f,&gt;,%3c,&lt;,%3e</FORMS60_BLOCK_URL_CHARACTERS>
940c937
<          <start_cmd oa_var="s_jtffstart">/s_u01/app/applmgr/jdk1.5.0_11/bin/java -Xmx512M -classpath .:/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/java/jdbc111.zip:/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/java/xmlparserv2.zip:/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/java:/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/java/apps.zip:/s_u01/app/applmgr/jdk1.5.0_11/classes:/s_u01/app/applmgr/jdk1.5.0_11/lib:/s_u01/app/applmgr/jdk1.5.0_11/lib/classes.zip:/s_u01/app/applmgr/jdk1.5.0_11/lib/classes.jar:/s_u01/app/applmgr/jdk1.5.0_11/lib/rt.jar:/s_u01/app/applmgr/jdk1.5.0_11/lib/i18n.jar:/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/java/3rdparty/RFJavaInt.zip: -Dengine.LogPath=/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/admin/log/finprod_acfpdb10 -Dengine.TempDir=/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/temp -Dengine.CommandPromptEnabled=false -Dengine.CommandPort=11000 -Dengine.AOLJ.config=/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/appl/fnd/11.5.0/secure/acfpdb10_finprod.dbc -Dengine.ServerID=5000 -Ddebug=off -Dengine.LogLevel=1 -Dlog.ShowWarnings=false -Dengine.FaxEnabler=oracle.apps.jtf.fm.engine.rightfax.RfFaxEnablerImpl -Dengine.PrintEnabler=oracle.apps.jtf.fm.engine.rightfax.RfPrintEnablerImpl -Dfax.TempDir=/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/admin/log/finprod_acfpdb10 -Dprint.TempDir=/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/admin/log/finprod_acfpdb10 oracle.apps.jtf.fm.FulfillmentServer >> /s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/admin/log/finprod_acfpdb10/jtffmctl.txt</start_cmd>
---
>          <start_cmd oa_var="s_jtffstart">/s_u01/app/applmgr/jdk1.5.0_11/bin/java -Xmx512M -classpath .:/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/java/jdbc111.zip:/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/java/xmlparserv2.zip:/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/java:/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/java/apps.zip:/s_u01/app/applmgr/jdk1.5.0_11/classes:/s_u01/app/applmgr/jdk1.5.0_11/lib:/s_u01/app/applmgr/jdk1.5.0_11/lib/classes.zip:/s_u01/app/applmgr/jdk1.5.0_11/lib/classes.jar:/s_u01/app/applmgr/jdk1.5.0_11/lib/rt.jar:/s_u01/app/applmgr/jdk1.5.0_11/lib/i18n.jar:/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/java/3rdparty/RFJavaInt.zip: -Dengine.LogPath=/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/admin/log/finprod_acfpdb10 -Dengine.TempDir=/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/temp -Dengine.CommandPromptEnabled=false -Dengine.CommandPort=11000 -Dengine.AOLJ.config=/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/appl/fnd/11.5.0/secure/acfpdb10_finprod.dbc -Dengine.ServerID=5000 -Ddebug=off -Dengine.LogLevel=1 -Dlog.ShowWarnings=false -Dengine.FaxEnabler=oracle.apps.jtf.fm.engine.rightfax.RfFaxEnablerImpl -Dengine.PrintEnabler=oracle.apps.jtf.fm.engine.rightfax.RfPrintEnablerImpl -Dfax.TempDir=/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/admin/log/finprod_acfpdb10 -Dprint.TempDir=/s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/admin/log/finprod_acfpdb10 oracle.apps.jtf.fm.FulfillmentServer &gt;&gt; /s_u01/app/applmgr/finprod/comn/admin/log/finprod_acfpdb10/jtffmctl.txt</start_cmd>
983c980
< </oa_context>
---
> </oa_context>
```

Comment: Why is the consumer not using a XML parser?

Comment: What is the encoding on the original file?  And does the output need to be xml or text?

Comment: The top of the file has the following: <?xml version = '1.0'?> Does that help?  The XML file is from Oracle Corp.

Comment: @Michael Ballent: amplifying the question of @Ignacio: is the consumer using an XML parser? what error message does the consumer produce? or is it possible that you are only guessing that `&gt;` will cause a problem? Show us an example of "affecting in all occurances of the XML document not just the node element"

Comment: @Michael Ballent: To avoid ambiguity and lots of guessing, please do this: Open your input file in a text editor (NOT an HTML editor) and show us the node that you are fixing plus say 30 bytes on each side. Then do the same with the output file. "show us" == "copy/paste into an edit of your question, NOT in a comment"

Comment: I think I did what you were asking for.  I am a complete Newbie to Python and this site. Thank you so far for looking into this

Comment: I'm going to be very blunt here. You're trying to solve a problem that shouldn't exist. Any decent XML parser will take `&gt;` and convert it to `>` when reading the text, therefore the problem, if any, is not in this stage.

Comment: @Michael Ballent: PLEASE answer these questions:  is the consumer using an XML parser? what error message does the consumer produce? or is it possible that you are only guessing that &gt; will cause a problem?

Comment: I am presuming that there is going to be an issue with Oracle's parser since it is not writing out $gt; in the first place. It must be doing that for a reason.  I have seen ksh scripts reference the xml file.  I will need to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminology: Parsers don't write XML; they read XML. Serialisers write XML.

In normal element content, `<` and `&` are illegal and must be escaped. `>` is legal except where it follows ]] and is NOT the end of a CDATA section. Most serialisers take the easy way out and write `&gt;` because a parser will handle both that and `>`.

I suggest that you submit both your output and input files to an XML validation service like [this](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/) or [this](http://www.validome.org/xml/) and also *test* whether the consumer will actually parse your output file.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification between Parsers and Serialisers as I said I am a complete newbie to Python and XML processing.  My xml passed using xmlvalidation.com but failed with validrome.org/xml with both the original file and the updated version.  I tested the files with other sites and it appears that the Schema validation is failing.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Michael Ballent: The parsers/serialisers distinction applies irrespective of language and file format. It might help if you said what validome (that's a dome, not a drome) was upset about ... but one can presume that it wasn't anything to do with the '>' or `&gt; issue. What does the consumer think of your output file? Please start a new question if you want help with schema validation.

Comment: The error was `Can not find declaration of element 'oa_context'`. the `&gt;` '>' did not come up at all.  I still need to test out the file with the consumer when I get an environment to run against.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is forcing the parser to treat the nodes you modify as cdata blocks (as the parser is clearly changing the xml tag closing brackets). Try `val.text = etree.CDATA(Value)` instead of `val.text = Value`.

http://lxml.de/api.html#cdata

Comment: Is not just the replaced value that is escaping the greater than > its is in the other nodes that I am not touching.